# Gatsby's Client Side Routing - What Gatsby features do my client-rendered pages still benefit from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, pagespeed

I built a small site that uses gatsby for static content, but then for some content that needs to be rendered on the client-side, I'm using [client-only routes in gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/).

I am not sure I fully understand how this works though - Say I have a *Header*, *Footer* & a *font* that I am using in my static site. On my client-only routes, I am using the same *Header*, *Footer* & *font*. **Will I benefit at all from having used these elements in my statically components previously?** Is the font being loaded anew, for example?

Basically, I would like to know what Gatsby-features my client-site content is losing out on now, and what I should maybe attend to a bit more, since Gatsby won't be handling this for me anymore. Especially in terms of pagespeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should benefit from having used those components and fonts already.

The React components that are being re-used will already be in a JS bundle that you have shipped to the user and shouldn't need to be fetched again. Likewise with the font files - but these will be asset files - not  in a JS bundle.

The best way to see what is being fetched will be to test it out in a browser.

1. Load a static page
2. Open the Network tab in dev tools
3. Navigate to a client-only page and check for network activity

While those assets shouldn't be fetched twice I can imagine some instances where an incorrect setup would fetch them twice - so best to just double check.

Answer (score 0):

> Will I benefit at all from having used these elements in my statically
> components previously?

The answer is yes. Gatsby works with `@reach/router` under the hood so you will have all benefits of it no matter if you use client-only routes or not.

In other words, the trickiest part of using client-only routes is the internal routing, for your site, in that scenario, Gatsby will handle the routing internally since it extends from `@reach/router`, so the shared components (header, footer, etc) will only be rendered on-demand and will be shared across your site, no matter if it's a client-only route or a static page.

> I would like to know what Gatsby-features my client-site content is
> losing out on now, and what I should maybe attend to a bit more, since
> Gatsby won't be handling this for me anymore. Especially in terms of
> pagespeed.

Summarizing a lot, when a page loads, `@reach/router` looks at the path `prop` of each component nested under `<Router />`, and chooses one to render that best matches `window.location`. So you will only render the needed code on-demand.

In terms of page speed, your site won't be affected because the site keeps being "static" and pre-mounted once the build is done. The only "negative" part of using client-only routes (if you want to say that) is the SEO part since they won't be intercepted by Google, but, that's the reason why you are using client-only paths, in most of the cases you don't want to index those pages.